# Wordpress - WP_Query (Load more post)

Tags: wordpress, wp-query

Спасибо, что зашли.

Вопрос: Стандартный код вывода кастомных постов. Как реализовать кнопку - "Загрузить еще посты". Чтобы сначала выводилось 3 поста, по клику по кнопке еще 3 и тд.

```
      <?php 
       $mainquery = new WP_Query(array(
      'post_type' => 'smi', 
      'order' => 'DESC',
      'posts_per_page' => -1
       ));
         if ( $mainquery->have_posts() ) {
         while ( $mainquery->have_posts() ) {
         $mainquery->the_post();  
         ?> 

            Блаблабла

        <?php }
        } else {
        // no posts found
        }
        /* Restore original Post Data */
        wp_reset_postdata();
        ?>
```

Comment: https://misha.blog/wordpress/ajax-pagination.html

Comment: Очень хорошая и понятная статья: https://www.billerickson.net/infinite-scroll-in-wordpress/